# GParted and character encoding problem

Tags: partitioning, xorg, gparted, encoding

I recently installed GParted and a Server X on my machine.

These installations are complete and are working fine.

When I start GParted over SSH, there is a strange encoding problem. I attached a picture of the result. I don't know how to solve that :S

[Picture show the problem when GParted is started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwG50.png)

I hope you can help me, thanks you in advance for your help !

Comment: Until you get an answer to  your question, if you have a spare usb flash drive you could install a bootable version of gparted as a workaround. Sorry I don't have an answer to your specific issue, but maybe the workaround will be sufficient for you. Good luck!